# I keep getting this error message for my python program: ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python

Everything else seems to be working fine. The requirements were that I use a for loop to get gather input for the students' grades, display a name for each student, compute and display the average of those 5 grades, and display the highest grade. I'm really not sure where I am going wrong here. Please help!
Here is the program below:

```
#this program will compute average quiz grade for a group of 5 students
#prompt user for quiz grade using a for loop for each of the 5 students

#assign names to student list
students = ["John", "Jake", "Jane", "Sally", "Susie"]

#grades: 90-100=A, 80-90=B, 70-80=C, 60-70=D, <60=F


#prompt user for student grades
for student in students:
    grades = eval(input(f"Enter the grade for {student}: "))

grades = []
sum = 0
for i in range(0,5):
    for i in grades:
         sum+=i
avg_grade=sum/5


#print average grade of students
if(avg_grade >=90):
    print("Average Grade: A")
elif(avg_grade>=80 and avg_grade<90):
    print("Average Grade: B")
elif(avg_grade>=70 and avg_grade<80):
    print("Average Grade: C")
elif(avg_grade>=60 and avg_grade<70):
    print("Average Grade: D")
else:
    print("Average Grade: F")



#print highest grade
max_grade=max(grades)
for i in grades:
    if(max_grade>=90):
        print("Highest Grade: A")
    elif(max_grade>=80 & max_grade<90):
        print("Highest Grade: B")
    elif(max_grade>=70 & max_grade<80):
        print("Highest Grade: C")
    elif(max_grade>=60 & max_grade<70):
        print("Highest Grade: D")
else:
    print("Highest Grade: F")
```

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to trace through your logic. What you are doing in the first part of the program makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the list `grades` is empty, as you have not appended any values into the list. You can fix it by doing:

```
grades = []

for student in students:
    grade = eval(input(f"Enter the grade for {student}: "))
    grades.append(grade)
```

Note that this change is at the top part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because your grades is empty:

```py
grades = []
for student in students:
    grade = eval(input(f"Enter the grade for {student}: "))
    grades.append(grade)
```